# why is it throwing me this error MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collectiresults index: words.meaning_1 dup key: { words.meaning: "情侣" }

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, express, backend

Previous Input :-

```
{
    "name": "Chinese",
    "word": "Lavdya",
    "meaning": "情侣"
}
```

Input

```
{
    "name": "Hindi",
    "word": "Lavdya",
    "meaning": "情侣"
}
```

Output :-

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: lingo-tingo.results index: words.meaning_1 dup key: { words.meaning: "情侣" }
    at C:\practice\Typescript\Language Learning App Using TS\Language Backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\update.js:70:33
    at C:\practice\Typescript\Language Learning App Using TS\Language Backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\command.js:84:64
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { 'words.meaning': 1 },
  keyValue: { 'words.meaning': '情侣' },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

"AddToResults" Function :-

```
export const AddToResults = async (req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => {
    const { name, word, meaning } = req.body;
    try {
        if (!name || !word || !meaning) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: "All Fields are Mandatory", success: false })
            return
        }

        let user = req?.user;
        let user2: UserType;

        if (user) {
            user2 = user as UserType;
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ message: "User is undefined", success: false });
            return;
        }
        let results = await Result.findOne({ name });
        const wordObj = { word, meaning }

        if (!results) {
            results = await Result.create(
                {
                    user: user2._id, name, words:
                        [
                            wordObj
                        ]
                }
            )

            let id = user2?._id as string
            let updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: 
                 { results: results._id } }, { new: true })
            } else {
                  const isDuplicate = await results.words.some((existingObj) => 
                  (existingObj.meaning === meaning))
                  console.log(results)
                  console.log(isDuplicate)
                 if (!isDuplicate) {
                let inresult = await results?.words.push(wordObj)
                console.log(inresult)
                await results.save();
                await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user2._id, { $push: { results: results._id } },
                { new: true })
                }
                 else {
                     res.status(400).json({ message: 'Word with the same meaning already 
                     exists ', success: false })
                     return;
                 }

           }

           res.status(201).json({ success: true, results })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        ErrorHandler(res, 500, 'Some Internal Server Error')
        return
    }
}
```

Result Schema :-

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ResultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    words: [
        {
            word: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            meaning: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            }
        }
    ]

}, { timestamps: true })

const Result = mongoose.model("Result", ResultSchema);
export default Result;
```

As in this i already mentioned that firstly it should check weather the results exists with the specific name or not if not exists than create a new result with that name and push that results id in user's results array .Now came to 2nd condition where i said  if there is a result that  check is that specific results have any works object with given meaning is yes  that throw response as 400 other just update the results array of provided name

But now there this issue arise when i try to create a word object with the same word and meaning but with a different name now as i already provided you **Inputs**  to you above there  if try to push that word object into Hindi named result array throws then provided error .Even the name of resulted array is different

And for confirmation i already provided you schema of Result

I want to that it should not throw an error when name of resulted array is different either they have same word or meaning object  it should throw the error when the resulted array  includes  the same object with  meaning